# How to export html page to ms. word (.doc) with external CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .doc

I want to export html page to .doc format with external CSS.
I'm using [jQuery.wordexport.js](https://github.com/markswindoll/jQuery-Word-Export) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

This is what I want to export:

```
<div id="export">Content</div>
```

And this is the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a.word-export").click(function(event) {
            $("#export").wordExport();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I also include the external css:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I can export html page to word, but the problem is it doesn't let me to include the external CSS. It works with inline CSS but it makes the code looks messy and I have to type the same style to every page. And also, it doesn't read margin and padding, so I cannot manage the position of the text.

Can anyone help me? I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put full path (Absolute Paths) of css file `<link href="{Absolute Paths}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` beause Ms-Word can't read Relative Path.

Example:

`<link href="http://www.domain.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I put `<link href="http://localhost:1337/test/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` and tried to put background-color there (on the table, I tried to export table), I can see the color in html page but it doesn't seem to appear in ms word.

Comment: I think  a problem became plugin jQuery.wordexport.js and FileSaver.js when you export to ms-word. this plugin don't include any css or js file into word file.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: hi @RashimCatalanDhaubanjar what do you mean by it didn't work? it cannot be exported or the css style is not applied?

Comment: @HerlinaAstari yes it worked I just had to use only those css accepted by ms-office  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx